# Unbreakable creature

Tags: creature-design

I want a creature with a skin/shell/protective layer which is immune to any form of external pressure.

If a bullet hits it, the skin hits the bullet even harder; if it falls from the sixth floor nothing breaks.

If a tiger tries to claw or bite into the skin, the skin moves off from the muscles making the sharp teeth/claws just slide off, akin to trying to stab a droplet of water: the water slides around the knife.

If a truck smashes the creature at maximum speed, the truck gets devastated.

Is all of this possible in one creature?

Comment: You're going to need either magic or imaginary technology (which is basically the same thing with different words used for the handwaving).

Comment: Yeah the ground always hits back exactly as hard as you hit it.

Comment: You want a *tank*.  A very big tank.

Answer (score 9):

## Not In Any Realistic Fashion

Or rather, you could conceivably have a magic skin that is impervious to all harm, but it wouldn't protect the creature - unless you treat it like the fictional metal [vibranium](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Vibranium) from the Marvel universe.

The key problem here is momentum.  If the animal falls from the sixth floor of the building, its shell/skin/whatever could be fine, but its innards would squish up against the side of the shell.  This is how people get concussions - the skull (often) doesn't get damaged, but the brain hits the interior of the skull because it doesn't stop moving when the skull stops.

If your creature is, for example, the size of an armadillo, if a truck hits it at velocity, even if its shell is intact, the creature will *die*, because its innards will be smashed into one side of its indestructible shell.  It also will do little or no damage to the truck, since it will just be kicked out of the way by the much greater mass of the truck.

But.  If you're willing to ignore physics and make the skin/shell/whatever magical, you can do what Vibranium does - absorb kinetic energy in a narratively useful way.  That is to say, Steve Rogers can move his shield around without any problem, but if it's struck by a massive hammer wielded by a physical god, or bullets, or energy blasts, it remains in place and conveys none of the impact to the wielder.  This makes exactly zero sense in the real world, but certainly looks good on screen.

Comment: what if the impact spreads only one the surface and doesn't pass from one part to the other of animal? would it be possible? like when punching water, the impact spreads more one the surface than it does on depth

Comment: @sleeves - that would require that the skin/shell/whatever be able to dissipate, rather than withstand, the energy transfer.  For things like bullets or knives, that's possible.  For things like falls and being hit by a truck, it is not, because sudden stops are sudden stops.